# NullPointerException Error on an Image

Tags: java, arraylist, graphics, nullpointerexception, bufferedimage

I'm working in Java and I wanted to create an arrayList of BufferedImages:

```
ArrayList<BufferedImage> aNoteList = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
```

I then want to populate the arrayList with 197 BufferedImages in the constructor of the DrawPanel class.

```
public DrawPanel(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 197; i++){
        try {
            aNoteList.add(ImageIO.read(new File("a.png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
    panelSize=getPreferredSize();
    height=(int) panelSize.getHeight();
    width=(int) panelSize.getWidth();
    System.out.printf("%d, %d\n",height,width);
    loadImage();        
}
```

Then, in the DrawFrame class, I create an object out of the DrawPanel class called canvas. I then use canvas here.

```
/*this checks to see if the song is at a specified time and calls the fall method in the DrawPanel class.*/

public void checkIfFall() throws IOException{
    if(Song.getTime() / 1000000000 == (jojo.getaArray()[canvas.getaI()] /1000000000)){
            //System.out.println("A Fall");
            canvas.fall(canvas.getANoteList().get(canvas.getaI() + 1), canvas.getLocA());
            canvas.setaI(canvas.getaI()+1);
    }
}
```

I suspect the real issues lie with the fall method, but I don't know why.

```
public void fall(BufferedImage img, Location loc) throws IOException{
    if(img != null){
    if(img == ImageIO.read(new File("a.png")))
        x = 10;
    if(img == ImageIO.read(new File("s.png")))
        x = (width-s.getWidth())/2;
    if(img == ImageIO.read(new File("d.png")))
        x = width-d.getWidth()-20;
    if(loc.getY()<=height){
        System.out.println(img);
        //offgc.drawImage(img, x, loc.getY(), null);
        validate();
        repaint();
        makeMove(movePixel(), loc);
    }
    }
}
```

I'm getting a nullPointerException when I pass image into the drawImage method, but I don't know why. The array is populated, it said that the image wasn't null. What's wrong?!
When I print out the image, I got this:

```
BufferedImage@614c5515: type = 6 ColorModel: #pixelBits = 32 numComponents = 4 color space = java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace@1e67b872 transparency = 3 has alpha = true isAlphaPre = false ByteInterleavedRaster: width = 50 height = 50 #numDataElements 4 dataOff[0] = 3
```

Does that mean anything?

Comment: There's no way any of the `img == ImageIO.read(...)` conditions would be `true` since `ImageIO.read` is returning a new object and you are comparing references.

Comment: Can you post the source of `drawImage`? Is that a method that you wrote?

Comment: `I'm getting a nullPointerException when I pass image into the drawImage method` Where is drawImage? Is this from the `Graphics` class, and if so is the `Graphics` instance null? If you have an exception, it helps to post the code where the exception occurs, as well as the full stack trace.

Comment: drawImage is from the graphics class I imported.

Answer (score 0):

As image is not null, it can only be the Graphics object offgc or the loc object that you call getY() on. Try printing out those two to see if they are null. Also including a full stack trace would be helpful.